# How to get the string in a combobox with w2ui?

Tags: javascript, combobox, tags, w2ui

I want to select or type a text in a combox with the frameworks w2ui. When i  type on the key "Enter", i would get the value in the combobox to push this value in a array (see my addItem function in my code). I don't know how to access the string in the combobox ?

The documentation for this combo is here : http://w2ui.com/web/docs/1.5/form/fields-list

I have made a jsfiddle about what i'm trying to do here :
https://jsfiddle.net/espace3d/bLughmy9/

This is for a simple todo list with tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>W2UI Demo: fields-3</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/vitmalina/w2ui/master/dist/w2ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://rawgit.com/vitmalina/w2ui/master/dist/w2ui.min.css" />
</head>
<body>

<div style="height: 10px"></div>
<div class="w2ui-field w2ui-span3">
    <label>Combo:</label>
    <div> <input type="combo"> <span class="legend">You can type any text</span> </div>
</div>
<div style="height: 20px"></div>
<style>
.w2ui-field input {
    width: 200px;
}
.w3ui-field > div > span {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

var data={
description:["georges","henry"],
}

var addItem=function(item){
        console.log(item)
        data.description.push(item)
        data.description.sort();
}

$('input[type=combo]').w2field('combo', { 
items: data.description,
});

$( 'input[type=combo]' ).keypress(function(event) {
        if(event.key == 'Enter'){
        console.log( "Handler for .keypress() called." );
        /////////////////////////////////////////
        //WHAT I WANT TO DO
        //addItem(something)
        }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the w2field object by calling `$element.w2field()`.

After that, you can access the content by calling `get()` on the w2field object.

Side note: `get()` may return an object, e.g. if your items are objects in the form `{ id: 123, text: "my text" }`, which would be valid for w2ui combo box or list fields.

In your case, you can change the code as follows:

```
$( 'input[type=combo]' ).keypress(function(event) {
        if(event.key == 'Enter'){
            console.log( "Handler for .keypress() called." );
            var w2ui_field = $(this).w2field();
            var value = w2ui_field.get();
            addItem(value);
            w2ui_field.options.items = data.description;
        }
});
```

Note that you will have to re-assign the new items to the w2field options, if you want to display them in the combo box.

If you don't want that, you can ommit the `w2ui_field.options.items = data.description;` part.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k548j0w1/

Comment: @espace3d please let me know if the answer was helpful. If it was, please consider to mark it as accepted and upvote. If the answer did not help please provide further information.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you.

To address my problem, I got the JSON object item of the list and got its id or text in the COMBOBOX as follows.

```
$('#yourlistid').w2field().get().id
$('#yourlistid').w2field().get().text
```